# How to remove a Windows installation if you have two on your computer?

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I have two Windows operating systems installed on my computer. One is Windows 7 or Vista and the other one is Windows 10.

I want to keep Windows 10 and remove the other one. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Type `msconfig` in the command prompt and click the `boot` tab. Delete the OS you don't want. Make sure it is the correct one, though.

Comment: MSCONFIG controls what gets loaded when you boot a specific Windows installation.  How would you use it to uninstall a different version of Windows?

Comment: Just click the boot tab and then click the OS version you want to delete and there is an option to delete it!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [How to remove a second installation of a Windows operating system from a partition](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888023) :

When you have determined that a second Windows folder exists on the
 same partition as your "working" Windows folder, follow these steps to
 remove the folder from the partition and to remove the startup
 selection when you start your computer.

> Start the Windows operating system that you want to keep.
>
> To determine the Windows folder that you want to keep, 
>    click Start, click Run, type %windir%, and then click OK. 
>   Remember the  folder that is opened. For example, 
>   the folder may be C:\Windows.
>
> Note This is your "working" Windows folder. 
>   Do not delete or remove this folder from the partition.
>   In Windows Explorer, find the Windows folder that you want to remove.
>
> Important: Make sure that this folder is not the folder 
>   that you identified as your "working" Windows folder in step 2.
>
> Right-click the Windows folder that you want to remove, 
>   and then click Delete.
>
> ```
> Click Yes to confirm the deletion of the folder.
>
> Click Start, right-click My Computer, and then click Properties.
> ```
>
> On the Advanced tab, under Startup and Recovery, click Settings.
>
> The Startup and Recovery dialog box appears.
>       Under System startup, click Edit to modify the Boot.ini file.
>
> ```
> The Boot.ini file opens in Notepad and looks similar to the following:
> ```

```
[boot loader]
 timeout=30
 default=multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS
[operating systems]
 multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS="Microsoft Windows XP Professional" 
 /fastdetect
 multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS.0="Microsoft Windows XP Home" 
 /fastdetect
```

> On the File menu in Notepad, click Save As, 
>   and then save a backup copy of the Boot.ini file that is named Boot.old.
>
> On the File menu, click Exit to close the backup copy of the 
>   Boot.ini file.
>
> In the Startup and Recovery dialog box, under System startup, 
>   click Edit to reopen the Boot.ini file.
>
> In the [boot loader] section of the Boot.ini file, 
>   identify and then delete the line of text for the Windows operating 
>   system that you
>   want to remove. For example, if the Windows folder that you removed in
>   step 4 was for the Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition operating system,
>   remove the following line of text from the Boot.ini file:
>
> ```
> multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(1)\WINDOWS.0="Microsoft Windows XP Home" 
> /fastdetect
> ```
>
> On the File menu, click Save to save your changes to the Boot.ini file.
>
> On the File menu, click Exit to close the Boot.ini file.
>
> Click OK to close the Startup and Recovery dialog box.
>
> Restart your computer.